# Why  use a resistor when blocking DC?

Tags: dc, passive-networks

This may be a silly question, but I was wondering about the resistor involvement of a DC blocking network employed at frequencies 5MHz to 2400MHz.

Most of the designs I have seen are an RC arrangement:

```
----||-----
       |
       R
      ///
```

Now the RC combination I know develops the a time constant on charge and discharge.

However, if you are just wanting to block the DC part, why put a R in at all?

From I remember the statement was always (when regarding AC and caps), what happens on one side happens on the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amongst other things the resistor serves to provide "DC restoration".
 ie it gives the output AC waveform something to vary relative to.

Imagine you were going to use a comparator to provide zero crossing information about the AC signal. Without the resistor the question is "zero relative to what?". In the real world an isolated output may acquire or lose charge. The drive capacitor may leak, light may selectively remove or add electrons to the output circuit, the wind from the mountains may have electrons stripped off its molecules and it may then deposit positive charge on the output circuit - which unlikely sounding circumstance is what happens with the French Mistral and various other winds.  The resistor provides a reference path. Anything big enough to move the output relative to ground must drive the resistor and so have finite / real power.

As you say - the RC form a low pass filter.

Comment: Wow, a wind can do all that... :) Never would have thought. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: The wind part was a bit whimsical but essentially true. I was trying to highlight the fact that if a "node" is floating it can float anywhere and the effect can cause many problems. | Re "Mistral" - information only, there are a number of locations where a persisent dry wind, usually off mountains, gets stripped of negative ions and is net positive and is though by many to cause many health and behavioural issues. Truth of beliefs uncertain but results seem real.  Mistral, Foehn, Shuav, Hamsim, Sanata Ana, Chinkook, Sirocco [discussed here](http://www.causeof.org/positive.htm)